# Default option for javascript/jQuery filter hides all table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Please take a look at the following jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/42/

As you can see the table filter ('.filter-gift') populates itself with data from the HTML table below it. I have hidden all other scripts to make this easier to see.

The problem is when I select a filter for instance "Free TV" the corresponding table filters correctly, but if I then select the default filter option in the table the filter hides all rows.

Ideally selecting the default option "-Select-" should display all rows, how can I change my code so this is the case with my function.

**jQuery/Javascript used:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter-gift').each(filterItems);
});

function filterItems(e) {
    var items = [];
    var table = '';
    tableId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag')

      var listItems = "";
        listItems += "<option value='0'> -Select- </option>";
        $('div[tag="' + tableId + '"] table.internalActivities .information').each(function (i) {
            var itm = $(this)[0].innerText;
            if ($.inArray(itm, items) == -1) {
                items.push($(this)[0].innerText);
                listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + $(this)[0].innerText + "</option>";
            }
        });

    $('div[tag="' + tableId+ '"] .filter-gift').html(listItems);

    $('.filter-gift').change(function () {
        var tableIdC = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag');

        var text = $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] select option:selected')[0].text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "");;
            $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] .product-information-row').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "") == text) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).prev().show();
                    $(this).next().show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).prev().hide();
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }
            });           
        });     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set value to 999 > use if($(this).val()!= 999) else statement as below

```
$('.filter-gift').change(function () {
    if($(this).val()!= 999) {
        var tableIdC = $(this).parent().parent().attr('tag');

        var text = $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] select option:selected')[0].text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "");;
            $('div[tag="' + tableIdC + '"] .product-information-row').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| |)/gm, "") == text) {
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).prev().show();
                    $(this).next().show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).prev().hide();
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }
            }); 
            } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('table tr').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Whilst this stops the hiding of all rows when selecting the default option "-Select-" is selected it doesn't refilter the table to show all rows, which is what I want the default option to do.

Comment: then add an 'else' part for that 'if' and code to view all rows according to your logic

Comment: I don't know how to do it thats why I asked for help can you see the problem in my code?

Comment: i added the else part in the code above. hope helps

Comment: seems to break the function? can you show me in jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/42/

Comment: yes, i figure out that your option value for  select is o and also same for free TV. either change Free TV value to 1 or select value to "".  <option value="0"> -Select- </option> and <option value="0">Free TV</option>. are these options generated through jquery?

Comment: Yeah there generated in jQuery - all the code is in the jsfiddle for it.

Comment: can you change the value from there? i cant access that file from jsfiddle. note that the problem is same for all drop-downs. its a bad practice to set same value for 2 options in one drop-down. ping for any help

Comment: there is a loop in the jQuery that assigns values i think from (i) i think it would be a lot easier to just change the value of "-Select-" as I can manually assign any number to it such as 999 then have an if is 999 $(this).parent().parent().find('table tr').hide(); else run my code you think?

Comment: Or have if $(this).html()!= "-Select-")

Comment: yes you right that works too, @Scott even  better $(this).find(':selected').text() != "-Select-" please choose the answer right if its works for you. at least we identity the problem area also the comment thats identify the problem correctly. that will help others to quickly get into the topic. good day

Comment: looks nice, please vote for the answer and important comments.

Comment: good practice is to use empty string "" for such select options, it just a message for use no need to hold any value. this approach is followed everywhere. if your list not cross to value 999 in future, its ok, even you can make it more far like 9999.

Comment: should i modify to change to an empty value if so how would i check for the empty value?

Comment: if( $(this).val()!= "" )

Comment: Syed after activating my other functions I have a problem with the filter not working with hidden elements due to my paging method - it only runs through the data that is visible to populate the filter please take a look tell me what you think https://jsfiddle.net/51Le6o06/47/

Comment: nevermind i fixed it by running the filter before the paging thanks for your help!

Comment: new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105299/filtering-hidden-data-pagination-issue-jquery-javascript